# 30 million row monthly CSV that requires fields added on each line based on a lookup from a separate file

Tags: windows, csv, etl, scripting-language

I have a 30 million row CSV that gets created each month, I am trying to add 2 fields that are populated based on a Lookup from a separate file and let it run unattended. I am trying to choose the technology right now - I'd rather use a scripting language that can be run from the command line (Windows) and something free ideally but open to suggestions. SQL database not really an option.

Comment: For a file size that big, you may consider something which supports multithreading.

Comment: There is a nice list of tools that may be applicable here: [Structured Text Tools](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools). A number will do joins on CSV files. It's not clear from the description if joins against CSV files will address the problem, but it may be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to try POSIX join and awk

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Pentaho Data Integration. It’s Java based, multi-threaded and can cope with large CSV files at 100k+ rows per second.

You can call it from the command line in either linux or windows, and can parametrize the jobs and transformations to take command line parameters for things such as file paths, db connections, etc.

There’s a paid for Enterprise Edition but also a free, open source community version.

See community.pentaho.com.

Beware: steep learning curve. Shout if you need additional pointers.